# Infix to postfix notation in Haskell (Shunting-yard algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, parsing, haskell, math-expression-eval

I've written an infix to postfix converter in Haskell using the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Example of how it works:

```
$ ./in2post 
2 + 2
2 2 +
$ ./in2post
1 + 2 * 3
1 2 3 * +
$ ./in2post 
  (5 - 4) * 3+1005/(12-6*(12   -8)  ) 
5 4 - 3 * 1005 12 6 12 8 - * - / +
$ ./in2post 
(2 + 45
2 45 + ERROR
```

And the source code:

**Main.hs**

```
module Main (main) where

import System.IO
import InToPost

main :: IO ()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let tokens  = tokenise line
        newexpr = shuntYard [] [] tokens
    putStrLn $ untokenise newexpr
```

**InToPost.hs**

```
module InToPost
    ( Token(TNum, TOp)
    , Operator
    , splitTok
    , tokenise
    , untokenise
    , shuntYard
    ) where

import Data.Char (isSpace, isDigit)
import Data.List (groupBy)

data Token = TNum Int
           | TOp Operator
           deriving (Show)
data Operator = Add
              | Sub
              | Mult
              | Div
              | LBrace
              | RBrace
              deriving (Show, Eq)

splitTok :: String -> [String]
splitTok = groupBy (\x y -> isDigit x && isDigit y) . filter (not . isSpace)

str2tok :: String -> Either String Token
str2tok tkn@(c:_)
    | isDigit c = Right $ TNum $ read tkn
    | otherwise = case tkn of
        "+" -> Right $ TOp Add
        "-" -> Right $ TOp Sub
        "*" -> Right $ TOp Mult
        "/" -> Right $ TOp Div
        "(" -> Right $ TOp LBrace
        ")" -> Right $ TOp RBrace
        _   -> Left  $ "No such operator: \"" ++ tkn ++ "\""

tok2str :: Token -> String
tok2str (TNum t) = show t
tok2str (TOp t) = case t of
    Add  -> "+"
    Sub  -> "-"
    Mult -> "*"
    Div  -> "/"
    _    -> "ERROR"

precedence :: Operator -> Int
precedence Add    = 1
precedence Sub    = 1
precedence Mult   = 2
precedence Div    = 2
precedence LBrace = 3
precedence RBrace = 3

-- shuntYard (Operator stack) (Token Queue) (Token Buffer) = new Token Queue
shuntYard :: [Operator] -> [Token] -> [Either String Token] -> Either String [Token]
shuntYard _ _ (Left s:_) = Left s
shuntYard stack queue [] = Right $ queue ++ map TOp stack
shuntYard stack queue (Right (TNum t):ts) = shuntYard stack (queue ++ [TNum t]) ts
shuntYard stack queue (Right (TOp t):ts) =
    shuntYard ustack uqueue ts
  where
    (ustack, uqueue) = case t of
        LBrace -> (t : stack, queue)
        RBrace -> (stail srest, queue ++ map TOp sstart)
        _      -> (t : ssend, queue ++ map TOp ssops)
    (sstart, srest) = break (==LBrace) stack
    currprec = precedence t
    (ssops, ssend) = span (\op -> precedence op > currprec && op /= LBrace) stack
    stail :: [a] -> [a]
    stail (x:xs) = xs
    stail [] = []

tokenise :: String -> [Either String Token]
tokenise = map str2tok . splitTok

untokenise :: Either String [Token] -> String
untokenise (Left s) = s
untokenise (Right ts) = unwords . map tok2str $ ts
```

Please tell me, what are my bad practices here? For example, the use of `Either` felt really awkward and I'm sure it can be done better. Also, the `case` expression in `str2tok` is quite ugly.

Comment: I would rather recommend not to use explicit recursion in your yard. It might look [like this](https://gist.github.com/reverofevil/a444760c1aaa87fcffa0d794b1825c5f).

Answer (score 2):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn $ case traverse str2tok $ splitTok line of
    Left s -> s
    Right ts -> unwords $ map tok2str $ shuntYard ts

-- shuntYard (Token Buffer) = new Token Queue
shuntYard :: [Token] -> [Token]
shuntYard ts = concat queue ++ stack where
  (queue, stack) = (`runState` []) $ for ts $ state . \case
    TNum t -> ([TNum t],)
    TOp LBrace -> ([],) . (LBrace :)
    TOp RBrace -> (map TOp *** drop 1) . break (==LBrace)
    TOp t -> (map TOp *** (t:)) . span (\op -> precedence op > precedence t && op /= LBrace)
```

Or perhaps:

```
(queue, stack) = (`runState` []) $ for ts $ \case
  TNum t -> return [TNum t]
  TOp LBrace -> [] <$ modify (LBrace:)
  TOp RBrace -> do
    sstart <- state $ break (==LBrace)
    modify (drop 1)
    return $ map TOp sstart
  TOp t -> do
    ssops <- state $ span $ \op -> precedence op > precedence t && op /= LBrace
    modify (t:)
    return $ map TOp ssops
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but I can't get this code to compile. I've pasted it into the `InToPost.hs` file and compiled with `ghc -dynamic -XLambdaCase -O2 InToPost.hs`, but ghc spits out errors: `Illegal tuple section: use TupleSections`.

Comment: You'll need to enable the TupleSections language extension. Also LambdaCase and I didn't list the imports - hoogle unknown identifiers.